# Load grid row data into CodeMirror - get CodeMirror reference

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, codemirror

I am building a small extjs 5.1 app for personal use, designed to save examples of functions / methods used in my extjs apps.

I've given the most important steps with the help of Navaneeth-Kesavan and Tarabass in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416773/codemirror-editor-within-a-panel/32417405#32417405)

Now I'm struggling to load in CodeMirror editor the grid row data.

After several unsuccessful attempts, I am trying to load the data into a hidden textarea and then get value of this textarea and paste the value (setValue) in CodeMirror.

However, I am not able to get the CodeMirror reference.

I would appreciate suggestions to fix this.

By the way, what better way to do this?

[MiFiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/te0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeMirror element can be found as sibling of the textarea element. You can get reference to it by using the following code:

```
var codeMirrorInstance = textAreaComponent.getEl( ).query('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
```

Please refer below fiddle which I created by editing  yours.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tee

Comment: Thanks Navaneeth-Kesavan. Work great.

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined  codemirror.js:8478. However, in your fiddle works great. My itemclick method is in a controller file.

Comment: @josei, please try to recreate the error in a fiddle and post the link. I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks again Navaneeth-Kesavan. It was a syntax error that was hard to find.