# How can I activate by default, the code colors in CodeMirror (highlighting)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, codemirror

I am using Code Mirror in a Extjs5 app, with theme "abcdef"

However, code text is just white, no color.

How can I activate by default, the code colors in CodeMirror (highlighting).

To better contextualize see this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423702/load-grid-row-data-into-codemirror-get-codemirror-reference/32427386#32427386)

**EDIT**

My Textarea:

```
items:[{
xtype: 'textarea',
anchor:'100%',
// name: 'scripts',
itemId:'textareaItemId',
height:'100%',
autoScroll: true,
listeners: {
        afterrender:function(textarea){
            var editableCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea.getEl().query('textarea')[0], {
                  mode: "javascript",
                  theme: "abcdef",
                  lineNumbers: true,
                  keyMap:"sublime",
                  content: '',
                  matchBrackets: true,
                  electricChars:true,
                  autoClearEmptyLines: true,
                  extraKeys: {"Enter": "newlineAndIndentContinueComment"}
            });
            editableCodeMirror.setSize('100%', '100%');
        }
    }
}],
```

My itemClick method on grid listeners:

```
itemclick: function(grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
    var textAreaForCodeMirror = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#textareaItemId')[0];
    var editableCodeMirror = textAreaForCodeMirror.getEl( ).query('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
    editableCodeMirror.getDoc().setValue(record.get('scripts'));
},
```

CodeMirror files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CodeMirror/theme/abcdef.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CodeMirror/theme/base16-dark.css">

<script src="CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>

<!-- EDIT missing the following file -->
<script src="CodeMirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script> 

<script src="CodeMirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="CodeMirror/addon/comment/continuecomment.js"></script>

<script src="CodeMirror/addon/runmode/colorize.js"></script>

<script src="CodeMirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js"></script>
<script src="CodeMirror/addon/hint/html-hint.js"></script>
<script src="CodeMirror/addon/hint/css-hint.js"></script>
<script src="CodeMirror/addon/hint/anyword-hint.js"></script>
<script src="CodeMirror/addon/hint/sql-hint.js"></script>
<script src="CodeMirror/addon/lint/lint.js"></script>

<script src="CodeMirror/keymap/sublime.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you load and enable a language mode? I.e. load the script that implements the language you are using, and set the `mode` option. (And make sure the mode script has been loaded before you initialize the editor.)

Comment: Thanks Marijn for help. I edit my post with my code. I've tried using all kinds of mode without success. I can not understand if something is wrong in my code or lack some CodeMirror file.

Comment: I don't see `CodeMirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js` anywhere in there.

Comment: Thank Marijn. Actually missing this file, inserted after <script src = "CodeMirror / lib / codemirror.js"> </ script> (if placed before giving error). Maybe you can put your last comment in a answer so I can give my vote (is more than deserved: the help was very useful and effective) and mark the post as answered. Now works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you load and enable a language mode? I.e. load the script that implements the language you are using, and set the mode option. (And make sure the mode script has been loaded before you initialize the editor.)